# Вариация букв Ц и Ч

Tags: этимология

@Следопыт в своем [вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/research/30518) говорит о чередовании букв Ч и Ц, иврите и русских фамилиях. (b-s)

Насчет иврита все понятно. В русском языке много слов, пришедших из иврита через идиш. Но почему не предположить, что перечисленные фамилии (Черненко и пр.) происходят от слова черный? Не к этому ли призывает "бритва Окама"?

Comment: Какие фамилии?

Comment: Следопыт перечисляет несколько: Черников, Чернявский, Черномырдин ...

Comment: Кто такой следопыт - и где на него ссылка в тексте вопроса?

Comment: Следопыт- один из участников форума. Я явно что-то не так делаю (первый день на форуме). Извините. Научусь - вернусь

Comment: Возможно, Вы хотели что-то прокомментировать, а получилось, что задали самостоятельный вопрос. Так?  
Я могу вам помочь это поправить, если вы согласны. Перво-наперво надо найти место, где этот Следопыт что-то там предлагает.   

Все, я разобрался!
Возвращайтесь скорее!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно прочитать [здесь](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=433.t8EDpDtz-N1qf4Slx6QCuQRBVGMWObDNzDIEm_a01F1VoqGqlcKEQp2rVkc7zroFtjcnVT5qP1gQ3FKJnkthdte5XFgmWu0TkTts3OKBv_nBZ07eZ8Qr3BHkfqoYJe4F4FkXH4FBR7PCg2mxjfyxGse2ppbR0mSuUKxp_VBnU81hs2DoM8mX4bVPE75ouXM9VMCyB3nCEUnUs1ouf84RCggBQfNUbEA7vz68z728M99arqRV0HEawMIhNQBREREQo5N_BW7OtvW3_vf_rvXfzg.13f0b7f61cf7c0f27cb850d4c3e558fca7b7370b&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xti-b8lArfpY2fz6fP4kJz3L2G-JPg-_BxbiFHA_182Y_UvGEFKIZa3wIZcRmNhx1wQkY7o4Nf9o2Ygihe8ppfF4w45Da-RqTVRRvdJTIERABenswIGQcdfTRk_1tj0WAtVf-dh1u-x4Ow2bTh3_iYDkWxSlBoX2HK2NICPDL7h6D8O-fmZ9B5k&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxZ1dZSVhkeXpkR2dCN1oxYTVDTHpfemxyLWR5R1lSdnJCU1N3bTN0MDh4Y2ZKUXc2UUc2cEN6LTVsbUZhWjAwMmk4dTFmWlNxa0M4X2VPbWdlVjlDeUpEeW5QemNJWUZ5RXpoU1h3UHZmc1M5aUJVb3B4NElsdw&b64e=2&sign=5c05766b14ac165e07d6f11d37583640&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1409471212776&mc=2.9477027792200903)

Answer (score 1):

> Я явно что-то не так делаю (первый день на форуме). Извините. Научусь - вернусь

Готово, возвращайтесь!!!

Вы попали в среду т.н. связанных исследований, а она здесь далека от совершенства, не слишком популярна, в ней трудно ориентироваться поэтому недоразумения возникают.

Посмотрите, это соответствует Вашим замыслам?!

По сути отвечу позже, если не забуду.)))

//--------------------------

Так, ну коли [[@Следопыт](/users/2568/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82)](/users/2568/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82) сам сюда пришел.
[[@innak](/users/4059/innak)](/users/4059/innak), Вы совершенно правы, говоря что нет никакой необходимости привлекать иврит или что-то еще для обоснования русских и вообще славянских фамилий. Тут дело даже не в бритве Оккама (хотя и она, бритва, вполне разумный довод). 
Все рассуждений о каком-то влиянии иврита на фамилии сталкиваются со вполне разумным доводом: ничем (кроме убеждения авторов таких теорий) не подтверждается. Они исходят из того, что любое фонетическое сходство есть основание подозревать родственность или влияние одного языка на другой. 
Это совершенно не так.

Апологеты собственных "оригинальных" идей совершенно не раскрывают механизмы такого предполагаемого родства или влияния. Для придания теории какой-либо стройности надо, как минимум, проследить историю слова (хотя бы и фамилии) в языке-источнике (иврит), его заимствования другими языками, родственными языку-мишени (русский) и фонетическую закономерность изменения слов при заимствовании. У нас нет по сути ни одного такого пункта.

Короче это сплошная чудиновщина (было такое чудо в лингвистике с говорящей фамилией), только с заменой древних славян на евреев.

Фамилии типа Черненко и проч. абсолютно русские или восточнославянские, тут и думать нечего.   
Диалектная мена Ч<>Ц в русском хорошо известна, есть "цокаюшие" и "чокающие" диалектные регионы. Причина понятна. В фонетике эти звуки считаются близкими аффрикатами (ТШ) и (ТС), а переход С в Ш хорошо известен не только в европейских - это тоже очень близкие звуки - отличаются только местом контакта задней спинки языка с верхним небом.
При этом следует говорить не об одном явлении, а об аллометрии (явлении описываемом теорией подобия).  Поскольку такие языки как, например, венгерский, португальский и японский, в которых наблюдаются в чем-то похожие явления позиционной или исторической мены С и Ш, уж никак нельзя назвать родственными.

Comment: Абсолютно соответствует (уже боюсь отвечать). Спасибо. Кажется, начинаю понимать...

Comment: Я сделал сегодня ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ в мой ответ . Приглашаю Вас , innak , и behemothus*а с ним ознакомиться .

Comment: Уважаемый следопыт, во- первых, вы оправдываете свой ник. Дополнение очень интересное. Спасибо. Во-вторых, давайте, действительно, не умножать сущности, как пишет @greydog. Евреи были народом пришлым и на необъятных просторах новых "родин" фамилии свои получали разными способами, в том числе по местности, из которой они пришли. Существует, например, фамилия Заграничный.

Comment: Помимо ЗАГРАНИЧНЫЙ есть ещё ЗАГЕР , ЗАГЕРмахер и ЗАГЕРСон , а также ЗАХАРЕНок , и ЗАХАРИН (последних особенно много) . Ветхозаветный пророк Захария - отсюда еврейское имя Захар .Заграничный произошёл от какого-нибудь ашкеназного Захрейна . Х переходит в Г , как в Herbert-Герберт , Heinrich Heine - Генрих Гейне и т.п. А , вот . фамилия Варшавский - он , что , из Варшавы приехал ? Может быть и такое , но , вообще-то ,  существует ветхозаветное женское имя Вирсавия , а у евреев до недавнего времени не было подразделения на мужские и женские имена . Есть и другие примеры такого рода .

Answer (score 0):

Дорогой (или дорогая ) **Innak** ! Вы , вероятно , невнимательно читали моё исследование о вариациях букв **Ц** и **Ч** . Я ниего НЕ ГОВОРИЛ об этом чередовании в ИВРИТЕ ! Я указывал на это чередование ТОЛЬКО В ЕВРОПЕЙСКИХ ЯЗЫКАХ ! В иврите мне о таком чередовании ничего не известно , к тому же в иврите , вообще , отсутствует буква обозначающая звук **Ч** . И с этой позиции я попытался объяснить происхождение некоторых фамилий . Вообще , есть немало фамилий , кажущихся вполне русскими , но , с равным успехом , могут относиться и к фамилиям еврейским . Вот , например , фамилия УТКИН , - *русская фамилия* от слова "утка" ? Но эту фамилию носил советский поэт 20-30-х годов Иосиф Уткин , написавший поэму о комиссаре Мотеле и другие стихи , касающиеся темы  евреев и революции . Сам этот поэт никогда не "маскировался" относительно своего национального происхождения . Откуда , спрашивается , у него фамилия УТКИН ? Я отвечу : есть еврейская фамилия ЮТ (мне известны конкретные евреи с такой фамилией ) , и какого-то еврея Юта по свойски звали *Юткой* , а далее от него пошли ЮТКИНЫ=УТКИНЫ  . И таких примеров я Вам могу привести много-много . Зайдите вот по этой ссылочке [link text](http://jmemory.org/) (Электронная книга памяти воинов-евреев павших в борьбе с нацизмом ), нажмите на строчку МЕМОРИАЛ , опуститесь по странице книзу и откройте алфавитный указатель на ЧЕ- . Там вы найдете обширную подборку солдат-евреев с фамилиями на ЧЕРН- , в том числе есть и  ЧЕРНОМОРДИНЫ , и ЧЕРНОМОРСКИЕ (а имена и отчества 100% еврейские ). Полистайте этот МЕМОРИЛ также на фамилии типа НИКОЛАЕВ , БОБРОВ и другие "русские" фамилии . Желаю Вам творческих успехов !======================================================= **ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ для greydog от 18.о9.2014г. по поводу его комментария .**                      ////// Уважаемый **greyndog** ! Благодарю Вас за конструктивный интерес к моему исследованию **"Вариации букв Ц и Ч"**  , опубликованному 14.02.2014г. . В этом исследовании я указал , что в европейских языках , включая русский , буквы Ц и Ч  имеют свойство варьироваться , и в этом аспекте дал этимологию некоторых слов , а также имен собственных . Именно в плане имен собственных и возникли возражения у форумчан ,  в том числе и ваши "непонятки" . Вы написали в комменте :" **... с Черномором - полные непонятки . Откуда у бабушки Арины взялся сборник еврейских сказок ? И каким местом "колдовской" сюжет соотносится с Торой ?**" Постараюсь разрешить ваши "непонятки" . Во-первых , встречный вопрос : а почему полагаете , что все сказки А.С.Пушкина суть литературный пересказ сказок его няни ? Я не являюсь пушкиноведом , однако и мне известно , что , например , сюжет "Сказки о золотом петушке " заимствован ( с переработкой , конечно) у писателя Вашингтона Ирвинга . (Материалы об этом Вы без особого труда можете найти в интернет-поиске . ) Теперь перейдём к царю Салтану .  Сказка эта была написана поэтом в 1831-м году , а ранее , в 1820-м , Александр Сергеевич путешествовал по Крыму и побывал в самых разных его местах . Вы когда-нибудь слышали о народе , называемом **крымчаки** ? Прошу не путать их с крымскими татарами и караимами . Их осталось очень мало (счет идет на сотни) , и они сами говорят о себе , что находятся на грани этнического исчезновения ; тут сказался гитлеровский холокост во время фашистской оккупации Крыма - фашисты расстреливали их наравне с евреями . Крымчаки говорят на крымско-татарском языке , но их антропологический тип соответствует семитскому еврейскому , а не тюркскому , и они , как и евреи , исповедуют равинистический иудаизм и носят традиционные еврейские имена и фамилии  . От караимов их отличает различие в иудаизме - караимы признают священной только Тору , а  "пророческие книги"  таковыми  не считают . В Севастополе (где я живу) одна старая крымчачка поведала мне древнее предание о происхождении крымчаков - вот оно . *Давно-давно в Крым пришли хазары и поселились на Мангупе . Хазары-мужчины женились на местных женщинах , и от этих браков произошли караимы . Хазарки-женщины выходили замуж за местных мужчин , и от этих браков произошли крымчаки .* Идём дальше . Хазар долгое время считали тюрками , перешедшими в иудаизм , но это ошибочное мнение сейчас опровергнуто , - от хазарского языка сохранилось шесть  десятков слов , которые первоначально считали словами тюркского языка , но при более внимательном рассмотрении все они оказались словами иврита .  Тюрки , породнившиеся с хазарами , были их союзниками , но не самими хазарами ( *теми , из 10-и "потерявшихся"  колен Израилевых , которые ушли за реку Самбатион , - остатки Самбатиона -река Маныч на Сев.Кавказе , -  о чем свидетельствует Ветхий завет* ) . Так , вот , в фольклоре крымчаков сохранилась сказка "**Падишах , его сын и красивейшая в мире**" . И в этой сказке очетливо просматриваются те же сюжетные мотивы , что и в "Сказке о царе Салтане" . Зайдите на сайт Общества крымчаков по вот этой , вот , интернет-ссылке  [link text](http://crymchaks.org/kulturnoe-nasledie/folklor-crymchakov/69-padishah-ego-syn-i-krasivejshaja-v-mire) , и , пониже оригинального текста на крымско-татарском , прочтите русский перевод .//////Теперь о "соотнесении" с Торой . Хочу обратить ваше внимание , на то обстоятельство , что хазары наряду с иудаизмом втихаря поклонялись и запретным древнесемитским божкам , с которыми на протяжении всей ветхозаветной истории рьяно боролись жрецы иудейского бога Яхве . То есть , хазары были *двоеверами* . Когда , после разгрома Хазарии князем Святославом , хазары переселились в центральную Европу , эта  тайная вера легла в основу европейского чернокнижия . Не случайно , в современном Израиле сефарды , "*правильные*" иудеи , конфликтуют с ашкеназами , потомками хазар и "*неправильными*"  иудеями (дело доходило даже до кулачных столкновений) . Следы этого хазарского *двоеверия* ещё сохранялись и у крымчаков вплоть до начала ХХ столетия . Информацию об этом *двоеверии* Вы можете посмотреть на том же сайте Общества крымчаков , - раздел Религия в Главном меню .(*Их Алла - это древнемесопотамский Эль , - Эллохим одно из добавочных имен бога Яхве , из которого мусульмане вывели Аллаха .*) Так что , Тора здесь остаётся в стороне .//////// И напоследок : выше , в первоначальном ответе , я дал ссылку на мартиролог красноармейцев-евреев , погибших на фронтах ВОВ . Зайдите по ней и посмотрите в нём : САЛаТкин Макс Григорьевич , САЛТАНов Лазарь Файвелевич ,  САЛТАНович Борис Григорьевич , САЛТАНович Шоил Лейбович , САЛТАНовский Ефим Иосифович , САЛТейский Ефим Израилевич . Найдите там же : ЧЕРНОМОРец Аркадий Абрамович ,ЧЕРНОМОРский Михаил Григорьевич ,ЧЕРНОМОРский Михаил Иосифович ,ЧЕРНОМОРский Нухим Евсеевич ,ЧЕРНОМОРский Шмуль Исаевич ,ЧЕРНОМОРцев Наум Григорьевич . //////// Я ЖЕ *СЛЕДОПЫТ* ,  ДОРОГОЙ **greydog** ! А НЕ КАКОЙ-ТО , ТАМ , ФАНТАЗЁР !

Comment: Уважаемый, Вы так и не пояснили "механизм заимствования".  
И, если для фамилий я ещё могу предположить "еврейские" корни ("выкресты"), то с Черномором - полные непонятки. Откуда у бабушки Арины взялся сборник еврейских сказок? И каким местом "колдовской" сюжет соотносится с Торой?

Comment: Уважаемый greydog ! Я сделал сегодня для Вас дополнение в тексте моего ответа , к которому Вы поместили свой комментарий . Пожалуйста , прочитайте мой ответ ещё раз .

Comment: Простите, но сказка, которую Вы привели, является **упрощённым пересказом**, по видимому, арабской сказки. Её начало есть в "сказках 1000 и 1 ночи" (Рассказ об аль-Асмаи и трех девушках, http://gatchina3000.ru/literatura/sheherazade/1001night_206.htm). А "царь Салтан" у Пушкина - это "султан" в оригинале. Не надо "умножать сущности".

Comment: Но всё-таки он С-А-ЛТАН , а не С-У-ЛТАН . А , вот , другой пушкинский царь - Додон . Могу Вам предъявить павшнго воина Додина Моисея Александровича , также добавить , что евреи своих Давидов уменьшительно называют Додиками . Что касается арабской сказки , то один и тот же сюжет может переходить от одного народа к другому , а арабы набрались от евреев гораздо больше , чем евреи от арабов (взять хотябы религию). И ещё о Черноморе - был ведь и другой пушкинский Черномор , карлик-колдун . "Вся сила карла в бороде", - Вы не замечаете тут иудейский мотив ? ... Волосатый Самсон .

Comment: Ещё раз повторяю. Сказка, которую Вы привели, является "упрощённым пересказом". Слишком многое остаётся "за кадром". Вы разве сами не видите, что это - **куски** разных сюжетов, объединённые в некое подобие последовательного повествования?  
Что же касается сказок Пушкина.. Просто спросите у Яндекса. Он Вам найдёт целую кучу материала (разной степени русофильства), в котором упоминаются дневниковые записи сюжетов, рассказанных Ариной Родионовной. И имя в дневниках не "Салтан", а "Султан Султанович".